# Electron modify a single menu item?

Tags: javascript, electron

So, I'm building a softare using [electron](https://electronjs.org/). Now I can add menu in the software from a template

```
var menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate([
  {
      label: 'Menu',
      submenu: [
          {label:'open'},
          {label:'save'},
          {label:'Exit'}
      ]
  }
])
Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
```

But how do I modify a single menu item. For example, say, the `save` menu is disabled by default and activated after the `open` is clicked. Also say after clicking `open` a new menu `edit` appears. I can create the complete new template in full and just change the previous template with the new. But thats a bad way and can't be a practical solution when I'm using several menus with several submenus. So can I modify just one single menu item of my choice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the menu items using:

```
import { Menu } from 'electron';

Menu.getApplicationMenu().items // all the items
Menu.getApplicationMenu().getMenuItemById('MENU_ITEM_ID') // get a single item by its id
```

After that you have several properties on the single menu item as:

```
- checked
- enabled
- visible
- label
- click
```

And you can customize your behavior as you want to.

Tested with electron `3.0.5`, before the `27 Sep 2017` the method `getMenuItemById` was not there and you had to loop over all the items.

Comment: @eular sure, that's fine. we can start a chat and do it but I need a couple of hours I am in the middle of a work task and I cannot leave it now. Does it work fine to you?

Comment: Yeah, fine for me. In the mean time I will try to solve the problem myself, lets see how it goes.

Comment: @Eular did you fix it? I am free now for a while if you want to

Comment: Well, It seems I can only set the boolean values i.e `Menu.getApplicationMenu().getMenuItemById('save').label = "test"` doesn't change anything but `Menu.getApplicationMenu().getMenuItemById('save').enabled = false` does disable the menu.

Comment: Okay after `Menu.getApplicationMenu().getMenuItemById('save').label = "test"`, this  `Menu.getApplicationMenu().getMenuItemById('save').label` shows `test` but the label on the menu isn't actually changed. Any fix for that?

Comment: I can only change boolean values as well. I think dynamic changing of menu items is not really supported.